# Change parametr (url and image url) generating file from XML

Tags: php, xml, url

I have a xml rss feed that I'm using on my website, with this code I'm generating html from xml file:

```
$html = "";
$url = "http://books.com/new_bookss/?format=xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
   $link = $xml->resource[$i]->book_link;
   $title = $xml->resource[$i]->book_title;
   $img = $xml->resource[$i]->image_url;
   $html .= "<a href=\"$link\"><img src=\"$img\"><br>$title</a>";
}
echo $html;
```

Generated $link and $img looks like this:

```
http://books.com/new_books/booktitle/   /*this is for $link*/
http://images.books.com/img/booktitle.jpg /* this is for $img*/
```

I have to change these urls that way:

`http://books.com/new_books/booktitle/`   to   `http://mywebsite/new_books/booktitle/`
`http://images.books.com/img/booktitle.jpg` to `http://mywebsite//img/booktitle.jpg`

URLs structure looks same every time:

`http://books.com/new_books/booktitle/`

`http://books.com/new_books/something/`

`http://books.com/new_books/else/`

Stricture on my website is same:

`http://mywebsite.com/new_books/booktitle/`

`http://mywebsite.com/new_books/something/`

`http://mywebsite.com/new_books/else/`

Same for $img, so the only thing I have to change is books.com to mywebsite.com

Comment: Ok I did it :)

    $link = str_replace("books.com","mywebsite.com",$link);

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
$link = str_replace("books.com","mywebsite.com",$link);
```

Added after:

```
$link = $xml->resource[$i]->book_link;
```